# correct sum of hours in access

Tags: datetime, ms-access, sum

I have two columns in an access 2010 database with some calculated field:

```
time_from time_until calculated_field(time_until-time_from)
10:45      15:00         4:15
13:15      16:00         2:45
11:10      16:00         4:50
08:00      15:00         7:00
08:00      23:00        15:00
```

Now so far, it is good: calculated field did its job to tell me total hours and mins... 
now, I need a sum of a calculated field....
I put in an expression builder: =Sum([time_until]-[time_from])
I guess total sum should give me 33:50... but it gives me some 9:50. why is this happening? Is there a way to fix this?

update:
when I put like this:

```
=Format(Sum([vrijeme_do]-[vrijeme_od])*24)
```

I get a decimal point number... which I suppose is correct.... 
for example, 25hrs and 30mins is shown as 25,5

but, how do I format this 25,5 to look like 25:30?

Comment: It is more formatting problem - 9:50 is time part of result, missing days count (1d = 24h). I would convert result into hours and minutes and format it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the answer from @HansUp, it can be done without VBA code like so

```
Format(24 * Int(SUM(elapsed_time)) + Hour(SUM(elapsed_time)), "0") & ":" & Format(SUM(elapsed_time), "Nn")
```

Comment: I like this more than mine.  Is there an advantage with that `Format` expression for the hours piece?

Comment: I don't think it makes any significant difference, just a tiny bit more concise.

Comment: I love you Gord! I'm in debt to you. This is so amazing. It works.

Comment: @HansUp Thank you too, for your effort. You guys are amazing. u saved me.

Answer (score 3):

As @Arvo mentioned in his comment, this is a formatting problem.  Your expected result for the sum of *calculated_field* is *33:50*.  However that sum is a Date/Time value, and since the number of hours is greater than 24, the day portion of the Date/Time is advanced by 1 and the remainder *9:50* is displayed as the time.  Apparently your total is formatted to display only the time portion; the day portion is not displayed.

But the actual Date/Time value for the sum of *calculated_field* is *#12/31/1899 09:50#*.  You can use a custom function to display that value in your desired format:

```vb
? duration_hhnn(#12/31/1899 09:50#)
33:50
```

This is the function:

```vb
Public Function duration_hhnn(ByVal pInput As Date) As String
    Dim lngDays As Long
    Dim lngMinutes As Long
    Dim lngHours As Long
    Dim strReturn As String

    lngDays = Int(pInput)
    lngHours = Hour(pInput)
    lngMinutes = Minute(pInput)

    lngHours = lngHours + (lngDays * 24)
    strReturn = lngHours & ":" & Format(lngMinutes, "00")
    duration_hhnn = strReturn
End Function
```

Note the function returns a string value so you can't do further date arithmetic on it directly.

Comment: thank you... I am a beginner, so I am afraid i am gonna have to ask you where to put this code... and how to call it... :) but thank you

Comment: Save it in a standard module.  You can use Ctrl+g to open the Immediate window in the VB Editor environment.  From its main menu, choose Insert->Module.  Paste in the code and save the module.  Do not use the function name as the module name.

Comment: Then to use it, I'm guessing you can change `Format(Sum([vrijeme_do]-[vrijeme_od])*24)` to `duration_hhnn(Sum([vrijeme_do]-[vrijeme_od]))`

Comment: On further review, I think Gord's answer should be easier for you.  I suggest you accept his answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to show the total in a text box? the correct expression would be `=SUM([calculated_field_name]).`

Comment: if I put name_of _the_calc_field then it doesnt work. The only solution is to put formula inside of sum