# Access Sum Function is producing the wrong result

Tags: sql, ms-access

got a sum problem in access. i got a table for hours with a notice for holidays but for one employee the sql statement is not working correct.... Normally it should be 120 hours but as result i get 96 hours.
When i delete one row from the hours table the result is moving up from 96 to 112 hours. I will add an screenshot and the code from the query. If you need some more informations pls ask me.

```
SELECT b.Name &' '& Vorname AS Name, MonthName(MONTH(a.datum)) &' '& YEAR(a.datum) AS Datum,  Format(24*Int(Sum(Gesamt))+Hour(Sum(Gesamt)),"0") & ":" & Format(Sum(Gesamt),"nn") AS Gesamtzeit, a.Bemerkung
FROM Stunden AS a INNER JOIN Mitarbeiter AS b ON a.MitarbeiterID = b.ID
GROUP BY b.Name &' '& Vorname, Bemerkung, MonthName(MONTH(a.datum)) &' '& YEAR(a.datum)
ORDER BY b.Name &' '& Vorname, MonthName(MONTH(a.datum)) &' '& YEAR(a.datum);
```

[image: Screenshot Table Hours and Result]

Comment: Please test if it calculates correctly when you replace your fancy formatting `Format(24*Int(Sum(Gesamt))+Hour(Sum(Gesamt)),"0") & ":" & Format(Sum(Gesamt),"nn") AS Gesamtzeit` with just `Sum(Gesamt) AS Gesamtzeit` • Of what data type is the field `Gesamt`? Can you include the field definitions in your question?

Comment: the field gesamt is a date/time field with time,24 hours. The formatting is to get the field gesamtzeit as time value. When i use Sum(Gesamt) and multiplicate it with 24 i get the right value but as double value like 101,5 hours. So now i have to format it back to a time value.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result as [text-table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Your sample data seems wrong as result returns`September 2019`twice, one with `Bemerkung: 'Urlaub'`, one with`Bemerkung: ''`.

Comment: @D3rk0n3r so it is obvious that the sum function calculates correctly. But your fancy formatting is messing it up! Why don't you just format it as time like `FORMAT( Sum(Gesamt), 'hh.mm')`

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thats correct, when they work i will not add something to Bemerkung so its right that i got it two times

Comment: Remove the format on`Gesamt`in table. Maybe you stored a Date/Time, not only a time but don't see that, because of the format. Don't format on table-level, format on query-level.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yea will try to. right now the result of FORMAT( Sum(Gesamt), 'hh.mm') is 00.00 need to find a format to get more then 24 hours.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ fancy format comes from [correct sum of hours in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161554/correct-sum-of-hours-in-access)(but should use`Fix`instead of`Int`or negative values will be rounded [Int, Fix functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions))

Answer (score 2):

As you have 15 records and:

`(24 * #08:00:00#) * 15 = 120`

some of your records hold a negative time value:

```vb
? #08:00:00#
08:00:00

? -#08:00:00#
08:00:00
```

So, double-check your values, like:

```
Select *, CDbl([Gesamt]) As TimeCheck From Studententabelle
```

Comment: Your [FormatHourMinute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39219790/9439330) function looks good (using Fix not Int) and may help OP too.