# Need help using a calendar table in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, calendar

I'm super new to SQL.

I need to run some SQL queries in VBA (Excel) - so I'm using ADO in Excel VBA to access Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 as a provider (which I think - correct me if I'm wrong here - is Access). Currently a work tracking program generates (of interest) a table with columns of User, Start Date, Duration like so (here's a sample snippet):

[What the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsSzH.png)

Not everyone is doing work on the same day.

I need to return a result that shows, for a given person on all possible working days, the sum of all Duration(s) they worked (then I need to do it again for their admin tasks, and then the rest is maths to understand efficiencies). It'd be great to return zero on days where there is no duration.

I've created a calendar table (with relevant dates in Calendar.Dates). This isn't giving me what I want though....

```
SELECT 
    [WorkData].Duration AS Expr1, 
    [WorkData].User, [Calendar].Dates
FROM 
    WorkData 
RIGHT JOIN 
    Calendar ON ([WorkData].[Start date] = [Calendar].Dates) 
             AND ([WorkData].[Start date] = [Calendar].Dates)
GROUP BY 
    [WorkData].User, [Calendar].Dates, [WorkData].Duration
HAVING 
    ((([WorkData].User) = 'User1'))
ORDER BY 
    [Calendar].Dates;
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Any help would be most appreciated.

I can't get any results for the days where someone didn't work.

Comment: Should provide sample data as a formatted text table, not image.

Comment: If you want to show every day for every person even when they didn't work, need a dataset of all possible person/date pairs. Can generate that dataset with Cartesian product query: `SELECT Dates, User FROM Calendar, Users;` Suggest you use better alias names than the Access default of "Expr1".

Comment: Makes no sense to have GROUP BY clause without aggregate functions. `SELECT Sum(Duration) AS Expr1, User, Dates FROM ... WHERE User = 'User1' GROUP BY User, Dates ORDER BY Dates`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [correct sum of hours in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161554/correct-sum-of-hours-in-access)

Comment: I'm going to suggest a reframe to the problem.  If you are going to go to the trouble of generating a calendar,  you may wish to include all dates iwithin range,  with a boolean attribute Workday that will let you select just the workdays.  You may wish to add the fiscal month and quarter the date belongs to if your company makes month and quarter boundaries at company specific places.  This can be enormously helpful when you go to do reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery and a left join:

```sql
SELECT 
    [WorkData].User, 
    T.[Start Date],
    Nz([Total], 0) As TotalDura
FROM 
    Calendar 
LEFT JOIN 
    (Select User, [Start Date],
    From WorkData
    Group By User, [Start Date]
    Having User = 'User1') As T
    ON Calendar].Dates = T.[Sta
GROUP BY 
    [WorkData].User, 
    T.[Start Date],
    Nz([Total], 0)
HAVING 
    [WorkData].User Is Not Null
```

Comment: OK, that gives me an output of User, Dates, Total though the Dates are limited to what's common to the calendar table and the WorkData table - is it possible to get an output that has a sum for every date in the Calendar table? I appreciate that this is somewhat 'spreadsheet thinking', though it'd make post-processing (for speed) considerably easier in this application.

Comment: Yes, that's because of filtering on the user. So, use two queries as shown in the revised answer.

Comment: Thank you Gustav. Getting closer; the first query doesn't return a User field (it's *, Start date, SumOfDuration) though I can input User manually. Then does as it's meant to - but it stops on a blank cell (where there's a date but no activity). Any ideas?

Comment: Oh. Try using a subquery. See modified answer, please (air code).

Answer (score 0):

using two queries to simplify the sql.  Assuming:

```
Durations format is unclear and not relevant to the answer so it is converted to minutes for the example

'Users

-------------------------------------------
|       UserID       |      UserName      |
-------------------------------------------
|                  1 | User1              |
-------------------------------------------
|                  2 | User2              |
-------------------------------------------

'Projects

-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     ProjectID      |    ProjectName     |     ProjectTypeID     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | Client1            |                     1 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | Admin1             |                     2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | Client2            |                     1 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 | Admin2             |                     2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------

'WorkDates

-------------------------------------------
|     WorkDateID     |      WorkDate      |
-------------------------------------------
|                  1 |          11/1/2021 |
-------------------------------------------
|                  2 |          11/2/2021 |
-------------------------------------------

'WorkData

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         ID         |       UserID       |     ProjectID      |     StartDate      |      Duration      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |                  1 |                  1 |          11/1/2021 |                510 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |                  1 |                  3 |          11/1/2021 |                720 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 |                  2 |                  2 |          11/1/2021 |                 20 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 |                  2 |                  4 |          11/1/2021 |                 65 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 |                  1 |                  1 |          11/1/2021 |                 10 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

then: unrelated tables are cross-multiplied so we get every combination of user and WorkDate

[image]

```
'sql

SELECT Users.UserID, Users.UserName, WorkDates.WorkDate
FROM WorkDates, Users;

'results
----------------------------------------------------------------
|       UserID       |      UserName      |      WorkDate      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | User1              |          11/1/2021 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | User1              |          11/2/2021 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | User2              |          11/1/2021 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | User2              |          11/2/2021 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

the first query behaves just like a table in a second query so we can add a calculated field to look up and sum duration:

[image]

```
'nz(whatever, 0) replaces nulls with 0
'# # hashtags delimit dates

Duration: Nz(DSum("Duration","WorkData","UserID = " & [UserID] & " AND StartDate = #" & [WorkDate] & "#"),0)

'sql

SELECT qryUsersWorkDates.UserName, qryUsersWorkDates.WorkDate, Nz(DSum("Duration","WorkData","UserID = " & [UserID] & " AND StartDate = #" & [WorkDate] & "#"),0) AS Duration
FROM qryUsersWorkDates;

'results

----------------------------------------------------------------
|      UserName      |      WorkDate      |      Duration      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| User1              |          11/1/2021 | 1240               |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| User1              |          11/2/2021 | 0                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| User2              |          11/1/2021 | 85                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| User2              |          11/2/2021 | 0                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can copy the tables into text files and import them into Access.  Sql can be copied into the sql pane of the query designer